# How to calculate proximity from lat long locations in a csv file using the Haversine formula

Tags: python-3.x

## Problem

I have multiple gps lat/long coordinates. I am using the Haversine formula to calculate the distance between user inputs lat1, lon1, lat2, lon2. It currently tells me the distance in miles between the 2 locations.

I'd like for the user to not have to manually enter them. I would like the user it enter a location id which will look up the lat/lon and then pass that to lat1 and lon1.

I'd then like the user to be asked to enter a search radius that would then show all the locations in that proximity.

## My 1st code for displaying the lat and lon of a user input

```
    with open("D:/Python/Data/rttData.csv") as csvfile:
        readCSV = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',')

        enbIDs = []
        enbNames = []
        enbLats = []
        enbLons = []

        for row in readCSV:
            enbID = row[0]
            enbName = row[1]
            enbLat = row[2]
            enbLon = row[3]

            enbNames.append(enbName)
            enbIDs.append(enbID)
            enbLats.append(enbLat)
            enbLons.append(enbLon)

    siteSelection = input('\nEnter the eNB number below to search for [ex: 25.806.1.1]\n')
    enbIndex = enbIDs.index(siteSelection)
    theName = enbNames[enbIndex]
    theLat = enbLats[enbIndex]
    theLon = enbLons[enbIndex]
    print('The name of site', siteSelection, 'is:', theName,'the Latitude is:', theLat, 'and the Longitude is:',theLon)
    state = 3
```

## My 2nd code for the haversine formula that calculates the distances between 4 user inputs to define the lat1, lon1, lat2, lon2

```
def distance(point1, point2):

    lat1 = point1[0]
    long1 = point1[1]
    lat2 = point2[0]
    long2 = point2[1]

    long1, lat1, long2, lat2 = map(radians, [long1, lat1, long2, lat2])

    dlong = long2 - long1
    dlat = lat2 - lat1
    a = sin(dlat/2)**2 + cos(lat1) * cos(lat2) * sin(dlong/2)**2
    c = 2 * asin(sqrt(a))
    r = 3959 #distance in miles around the earth
    return c * r

def get_location():
    lat = float(input('Enter the Latitude:'))
    long = float(input('Enter the Longitude:'))
    return (lat,long)


def main():

    user_selection = 'y'

    while user_selection == 'y':

        print('\nEnter the coordinates for your starting location below in decimal format.')

        point1 = get_location()
        print('\nEnter the coordinates for your ending location below in decimal format')

        point2 = get_location()
        dist = distance(point1, point2)
        rounded_dist = round(dist,2)

        print('\nThe distance between both locations is: {} miles'.format(rounded_dist))


if __name__ == '__main__':
  main()
```

## Final output should look like this

Hello user, enter a site:

> 25.806.1.1

The name of site 25.806.1.1 is: ABQ_BEARCANYON the Latitude is: 35.135056 and the Longitude is: -106.53475

Please enter a proximity search in miles:

> 20

The sites within 20 miles are:

```
Site 1:       5.23 miles

Site 2:      17.64 miles

Site 3:      19.88 miles

Site 4:      19.97 miles
```

Comment: It's not very clear what you're asking. Does the code you've shown work properly? It sounds like you want to extend the code to search some kind of database of locations, but you haven't shown anything about that. Where to does the location data come from? How large of a dataset are you going to be dealing with? A simple brute force search checking the distance from the starting location to every other point would work for a small data set, but if you have lots of data, you'll need a better algorithm.